# Alfresco Consumer Consultation with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, maven, alfresco

I am new to the use of Alfresco.
My query that maven libraries should import to use alfresco, I have a simple notion about consumption.

In my controller I will send an array of bytecodes, to a service with the following characteristics.

```
http://alfresco.estado.gob.pe:8080/alfresco

user: USUR0001
key: KEY0002
```

What I want to know is the simple code to send the array of bytecodes of the file, and that I generate a code to later download it.

I would appreciate it if you can guide me in the case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are writing your own application that is separate from Alfresco, and not part of the Alfresco WAR, you will not include any Alfresco libraries in your custom application's pom.xml at all. Instead you will likely use an HTTP client of some sort such as the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/).

As an alternative to using a low-level library like an HTTP client, you can use a higher-level library to work with Documents and Folders. In that case, your application should depend on [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/).

There are many [examples](http://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/) showing how to use Apache Chemistry to hit a repository like Alfresco.

Apache Chemistry can be used to work with any CMIS-compliant repository. To connect, you'll need to know your repository's "CMIS service URL". For modern versions of Alfresco, the URL for the "browser binding" is: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser